# Problema paralelización en R para descargar datos

Tags: r, funciones, foreach

Estoy intentando descargar los cif de un listado de 111.000 empresas más o menos mediante web scraping.

Para situarse, el cif de cada empresa está en un enlace distinto, es decir, tengo un enlace para cada empresa, unos 111.000.

Os pongo la función creada para la descarga de los cif que funciona bien:

```
extraer_cif <- function(x,cif){
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    try({cif[i] <- read_html(x[i]) %>% html_nodes(".text-right") %>% html_text
    }, silent = TRUE)
    print(paste0("Se han descargado CIF de:",i))
  }
  return(cif)
}
```

Hasta aquí está todo bien, el problema viene ahora cuando intento paralelizar el proceso para que sea más rápida la descarga porque sino es un proceso muy pesado y largo.

He estado buscando por ahí y lo he intentado con las librerías **parallel, foreach y doSNOW.**

Pongo el código de lo que tengo en la paralelización:

```
n.cores <- detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(6)

registerDoSNOW(cl)

prueba <- enlaces[1:100]

ver <- c()

ver <- foreach(i = 1:length(prueba)) %dopar% {
  extraer_cif(prueba,cif)
}
```

Las 3 primeras líneas de código no debería haber problema ya que es el tema de los núcleos del sistema.

Luego cree prueba para probar si funcionaba simplemente con los primeros 100 enlaces.

Y por último, a partir del foreach es ya la paralelización. Lo he hecho siguiendo ejemplos que ha hecho otra gente y parece que funciona pero el problema está en que **no me rellena bien el objeto ver y lo llena de NULL**.

Algún problema tonto debe de ser pero no soy capaz a dar con ello.

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de las urls que estás scrapeando para poder reproducir completamente el problema? Me parece que el problema es que no estás usando a índice `i` en la función `extraer_cif`, pero no puedo verificar. Dicho esto, la aproximación que estás usando no es la mejor para tu problema, por varios motivos es muy ineficiente. Si pones un ejemplo de los datos podría ayudarte a escribirla con la librería `future` que permite operación asincrónica y es mucho mejor porque no espera a que se resuelva cada ciclo para pasar al siguiente

Comment: Otra consulta ¿qué son los argumentos `x` y `cif` en la función `extraer_cif`.  ¿Podrías poner ejemplos?

Comment: Ya conseguí resolver el problema por mi mismo al final, no obstante muchas gracias por la ayuda mpaladino!